# previous form datatable change when it transfered to next form and make changes in datatable,Why?

Tags: c#, datatable, data-transfer

I have two forms named `form1` and `form2`,I have to transfer datatable `dt` from `form1` to `form2`.In `form2` constructor i pass datatable parameter `_dt` as you can see in below code and in `form1` button click i call the `form2` and pass argument `dt`.i properply get `dt` in `form2`.

```
//Form1 button click event
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //i have filled datatable dt
        form2 f2= new form2(dt);        
        f2.Show();
    }
//from2
 public partial class form2: Form
    {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         public form2(DataTable _dt)
        {
          InitializeComponent();
          dt = _dt;       
        }
    }
//change dt by adding columns in form2
```

when i change datatable of `form2` then datatable of previous form (`form1`) also change.i can't understand why `dt` of `form1` changed.please tells me why this happend?i have alternatives for this problem but i want to knows that why it happends.

Comment: You are passing the table by reference (an address not by value) so the two tables are actually one table.

Comment: but in form2 i create new datatable and assign previous _dt.

Comment: i means in form1 i create new datatable and in form2 i also create new datatable ,just initialize it with previous datatable,

Comment: If you are initialization then clone table which creates an empty table with same column names/type as original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only have one `DataTable`.  When you assign an object to a variable, you don't create a copy or clone of that object.  All you're doing is setting that variable to be a *reference* to the *same* object.  Think of it as having two variables pointing to the same thing in memory.

(As opposed to simple primitive value types, like `int` or `bool`, which do create a copy.)

To create a *copy* of the `DataTable`, use [its `.Copy()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.copy):

```
public form2(DataTable _dt)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dt = _dt.Copy();       
}
```